# What is ranger's show_hidden_bookmarks setting good for?

Tags: linux, command-line, dotfiles, ranger

Ranger's [man page](https://ranger.github.io/ranger.1.html) states:

> show_hidden_bookmarks [bool]
>
> Show dotfiles in the bookmark preview window? (Type ')

I played around with it but can not figure out what it actually does. My *bookmark preview window* looks exactly the same no matter if I set it to `true` or `false`. Can one provide an example where this setting makes a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer may be late, but it can still be helpful :)

A `show_hidden_bookmarks` option **set**s or **unset**s showing a bookmark that contains a folder beginning with a **dot** (show bookmark with `m` key), see more explanation in screenshot

[image: ranger show_hidden_bookmarks option]